# mass text replace using regex

Tags: regex, editor

In my latex code I need to change all expressions

```
e\left\{ something \right\}
```

to

```
\e{ something }
```

Any idea?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `sed 's/e\\left\\{\(.*\)\\right\\}/\\e{\1}/g'`

Disclaimer: I haven't tested it.

Comment: I tested it, you need to change the replacement to `\\e{\1}`. Otherwise it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. There is something wrong in it. For example If I have this text:    We shall use $e_{r}\left\{ x \right\}$ for $e^{2\pi i x/r}$. We set  $e\left\{ x \right\} := e_{1}\left\{ x \right\}$                                the code should replace the expression after "we set" but it does not work correctly. ? thanks